# Notification of which channel (not team) a bot is added to in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

In Teams, it's possible to create a bot with a team scope. When this happens, at install time the user is prompted to choose a team, and then specify a channel "where you want to use the app".

When the users chooses a Team, I see the `conversationUpdate` message with the `MembersAdded` list containing the bot, but when the users choose the specific channel, I don't see any message.  Is it possible to catch this event and respond to it?

Use case is: I don't want to put a welcome message in the General channel, I want to put it into the channel the user just chose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this is not supported. We have added feature request for this.